# Cloudfront path as a proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, reverse-proxy, amazon-cloudfront

I'm new to AWS and setting up a Cloudfront distribution. From what I understand Cloudfront is designed to be used as a CDN.

I have a single-page-app that requires to communicate with the api from the same domain under `/api/graphql` path pointing to a GQL server that is not hosted in AWS.
My question is is there a way to bypass the cloudfront cache for `/api*` and proxy to the server?

So far I tried to create a new custom origin in the same distribution setup a cache behavior for the `/api*` path to point to the custom origin, but it seems the viewer request headers are not sent to the origin server and things don't work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add/attach a cache policy for /api*.

See here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/working-with-policies.html

This way, you can disable cache for Cloudfront and forward all headers to your origin.